# PHP SQL server query

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I'm running a query to get the contents for a web slider.

```
$serverName = "livedata";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"User", "PWD"=>"PWD" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT Sliders.DisplayFrom, Sliders.DisplayUntil, Sliders.Sort, Sliders.Image, Sliders.Link, Sliders.Target FROM Sliders WHERE (((Sliders.DisplayFrom)<GetDate()) AND ((Sliders.DisplayUntil)>getdate())) ORDER BY Sliders.sort;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$maxx = 0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    $maxx++;                            
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo “<br>” . $row[‘Image’];
}
```

The second loop does not output any results. why? Is it because $row is already at the end?  If so, how do I move first like in ASP without having to create $result2 and $row2, 3, 4, 5, ...

Would it be better to use for loops like in vb.net?

```
 for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxx; $i++){
  
 }
```

But then How do I specify the output if I have no $row?

and if I only wanted to output the first row like I do in vb.net, how would I write the following in PHP?

```
dsqueryResults.tables(0).rows(0).item("Image");
```

would I still use a while loop and have a variable inside the loop to hold the row number and only output if row = 0?

```
$WhichRow = 0;
while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2)) {
    if ($whichRow == 0){    
        echo “<br>” . $row2[‘Image’];
    }
    $WhichRow++;
}
```

Comment: Are these the actual quotes in your code? `“<br>”` and `[‘Image’]`.

Comment: What does this have to do with vb.net?

Comment: Funky Forty Niner - I wrote the question in word before copying it into the website. Sorry word made the quotes word quotes.

Mary - I'm trying to duplicate what I do in vb.net in PHP. I tagged it as vb.net because I referenced vb.net code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $max++ counter inside the while loop if you really want to use that for other purposes.

If you just want a count then run a count query on MySQL or do an array count of returned result.

If you just want to print 1 row use

```
LIMIT 0,1
```

at the end of your query as there's no point in fetching all rows and waste resources.

Based on additional comments you can try this to get your current row number.

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$rownumber = 0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
$rownumber = $rownumber + 1;//Your current row number.
echo “<br>” . $row[‘Image’];
}
```

Comment: Keral - On the page that I've written, I use the output from the query 3 times. Each time I use the code I have to create $result, $result2, $result3 and $row, $row2, $row3 because once the while loop finishes, calling it again does nothing as the pointer is at the end of the array. The reason I need to use the query results multiple times is to construct Javascript functions next() and previous() for a web slider. I also have to output the first slider image. Since I need all the rows for the first 2 loops, I did that. In the 3rd loop,

Comment: I only wanted the first row, so I had to use a variable and restrict output to just the first row.  Referencing vb.net I can call just the first row by dataset.table(0).rows(0).item("field"). 

In asp, I could move first, previous, next and last within the output. Having control of the pointer allows me to use the same query results multiple times by using movefirst after the loop finishes.  I understand that the query results are put into multidimensional arrays $row[], $row2[], ...

Comment: This makes me loop through all the rows regardless of the fact that I want just the first. 

One of my thoughts was to use a for loop as I do in vb.net setting $i as the pointer and then reference the row as $row[$i, 'Image']. This way I could loop $i=0 to array length-1, incrementing $i as . . . . 

    for($i = 0; $i >= count($row) -1; $i++){
        echo $row[$i, 'Image'];
    }

I could also reference the first row by $row[ 0, 'Image'] and avoid looping all together. right?

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes that does gives me some idea and that is what I am trying to say that if you just want 1st row. Query the database as you are already doing it but add LIMIT 0,1 at the end of the query. That way you can just fetch the first row of the results.

Comment: And if you want 2nd row from results then just query as you are normally doing but add LIMIT 1,1 at the end of the query. For 3rd row add LIMIT 2,1 at the end of the query.

Comment: Updated the answer with additional information on how to keep track of current row number you are dealing with inside the loop.

Comment: Why make a second query to get the first row when I already have made a query to get all the rows? I know I can, but isn't the point to do less fetches rather than more? I want faster page loads. That's why I wanted to reference the value in the array using both dimensions so I didn't have to make a second query using limit 1,1 and then loop over the results. Looping through an array containing one row seems pointless. Am I on the right track here? Can I reference the value using $row[0, 'Image']? Will this work? maybe I should just try it.

Comment: I just tried to reference the array value using $row[0, 'Image'] and got an error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'. So then How do I reference the first row without looping?

Comment: simply run $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) and reference the first row as $row['image']. How do I move the pointer to different rows? Is it like asp with $row.movenext, $row.moveprevious, $row.movefirst & $row.movelast?

Comment: I just found one of the answers:  stick with the while loop and after the loop ends call reset($row) to put the pointer back at the beginning of the array so it can be used again. except that I'm getting an error:reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. I'm guessing that after the loop ends, $row no longer exists.

Comment: if that's true then why would calling a second while loop using $row, produce no output? I know it has to do with the pointer. right?

Comment: "How do I move the pointer to different rows?" While you are in while loop the pointer itself moves to the next row. That is why it is inside that loop. I did updated the answer already which will allow you to know which row you are currently dealing with while you are in the while loop.

Comment: So if I know the row I am dealing with, how do I then reference that row without starting a new loop. Lets say that I found that I later wanted to output row 5 again. Do I then have to create another loop or can I directly reference row 5? And how do I reference row 4 or 3 while in the original loop? What if I'm in a loop and need to skip ahead to check values and then back several rows to the current record. In ASP, I could recordset.MoveNext and recordset.MovePrevious and at the end of a loop recordset.movefirst.

Comment: In vb.net, I could incrament or decrament the pointer. 

Do I have control over the pointer or is it limited to looping in sequential order only?

Comment: If you want a pointer thing why not just push all the results into an array and then use the pointer to point to the item inside that array.

Comment: It is in an array. Its called $row. Im just trying to figure out how to reference the record. I tried $row[0, 'Image'] but got an error because of the unexpected comma. If i can figure it out then i could use a for loop instead of a while loop.

Comment: Make your own array with pointers that is what I am trying to say. $arr[] = $row; then keep using the $arr with 0 or 1 etc as keys to reference it. $arr[0] will return the first value and if you directly want to jump to 3rd value then use $arr[2]

Comment: so in this case it would be a multidimensional array and I could reference it using $arr[0, 'Image']. right?  If so then I could use a for loop to reference the rows when I nee to and then I know which row I'm outputting with the value of the pointer, $i.

Comment: In ASP, I loop while not recordset.EOF. How do I check the array to see if not EOF. Do I loop while $i less than or equal to the length of the array?

Comment: You're saying yes. Right? I'm just gonna have to find some time to play with some code and see what happens.